# How to get Elasticsearch 5.2.2 search highlighting working with Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, highlight

What is required to get the Elasticsearch Java API to return search highlights?

The code I'm using to construct the query looks similar to the following:

```
        final HighlightBuilder highlight = new HighlightBuilder()
                .field("*")
                .highlighterType("fvh");

        final SearchRequestBuilder request = client.prepareSearch()
                .setTypes("mytype")
                .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                .setQuery(query)
                .setFrom(currentPage)
                .setSize(perPage)
                .highlighter(highlight)
                .addSort(orderBy.getValue(), sortOrder);
```

Dumping the query looks something like this:

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 10,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
          "terms" : {
            "my.field" : [
              "myvalue"
            ],
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      ],
      "disable_coord" : false,
      "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  },
  "sort" : [
    {
      "myotherfield1.myotherfield2.myotherfield3" : {
        "order" : "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "highlight" : {
    "type" : "fvh",
    "fields" : {
      "*" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

I get results but the `.getHighlightFields()` method on each hit returns an empty map.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. The fields need to be selected individually, instead of using '_all':

```
  for(String fieldName : allFields){
      query.should(QueryBuilders.matchPhrasePrefixQuery(fieldName, queryText));
  }
  query.minimumShouldMatch(1);

  final HighlightBuilder highlight = new HighlightBuilder()
          .highlighterType("plain")
          .preTags("")
          .postTags("");

  for(String fieldName : allSearchFields) {
      highlight.field(fieldName);
  }

  final SearchRequestBuilder request = client.prepareSearch()
          .setTypes("mytype")
          .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
          .setQuery(query)
          .setFrom(currentPage)
          .setSize(perPage)
          .highlighter(highlight)
          .addSort(orderBy.getValue(), sortOrder);
```